# Filter data by a field with kendo multiselect (MVVM)

Tags: html, mvvm, kendo-ui, filtering, multi-select

Can I filter multiselect data by searching on a field?
This is my code now:

```
<select id="Multi" 
        name="multiselectData" 
        data-role="multiselect" 
        data-filter="name"
        data-text-field="name" 
        data-value-field="id" 
        data-bind="value: valueData,
                    source: sourceData,
                    events: {
                        change: onChange
                    }">
</select>
```

'data-filter="name"' doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data-filter` only accepts specific values as mentioned in their documentation.

> The supported filter values are **startswith**, **endswith** and **contains**.

Try to set `data-filter=contains`. It will automatically filter your data-text-field.